# Multiline cursor with skipping lines

Tags: eclipse, coding-style

I know Toggle block selection but sometimes I want to skip a line.

```
int number1;
boolean exist1;
int number2;
boolean exist2;
int number3;
boolean exist3;
```

I want to change prefix of the number only. I can use replace but prefer something like multiline cursor. I need it like this:

```
int number1;
int number2;
int number3;
boolean exist1;
boolean exist2;
boolean exist3;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have multiple cursors in Eclipse.

To rearrange lines move them with <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>UP</kbd> or <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>DOWN</kbd>. Eclipse's block selection mode is sufficient for most cases where you have to change block-arranged statements and you can easily change pre- or postfixes this way.

A handy extension is "AnyEdit" that allows sorting or converting all selected lines.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible, you can use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>click</kbd>.